# How to build a cassandra cluster with docker on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, docker, cmd, cassandra

I want to build a cassandra cluster with docker. [The documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) already tells you how to this so this is not the problem I have.

However I am currently using Docker on Windows 10 and obviously it cannot execute the nested command in `docker run --name some-cassandra2 -d -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' some-cassandra)" cassandra:tag` which results in an empty seed list for the container.

How can I nest a command like this in Windows or - if this is not possible - get a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it thanks to a [docker-compose.yml by Jason Giedymin](https://github.com/JasonGiedymin/docker-cassandra-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). It should work in v1 as well as v2 of docker-compose. By doing it this way you just let docker do the linking from the get go and tell cassandras about other seeds with the environment variable the container already gives you.

The `sleep 30` part is pretty smart as well as it makes sure that the second container doesn't try to connect on a container that isn't fully up yet.

One thing I would recommend though, is using `external_links` instead of `links`. This way other containers don't rely on all of the cassandra containers to be up to start/work. This would defeat the purpose of a distributed database.

I still don't know how to nest Windows cmd commands into each other so I would still be thankful for some tips.